# Leibnitz rule multiple integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $$h(z) = \iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:\; g(x,y)\leq z\}}f(x,y)dxdy.$$

How to find the derivative of $h$? Should $g$ be smooth? Is there a generalization of the Leibnitz rule to this case?

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but 
\begin{align*}
h(r)=\iint_{B_{r}(0)}f(x,y)dxdy
\end{align*}
is such that 
\begin{align*}
h'(r)=\int_{\partial B_{r}(0)}f(x,y)d\mathcal{H}^{1}(x,y)
\end{align*}
a.e. $r>0$, this is due to Coarea formula.

Comment: I guess that the coarea formula gives a sufficiently general answer to OP's question, so I wonder why you only considered a special case...

Comment: Which version of coarea formula you have seen before? You may edit my answer if you wish, thank you.

Comment: The version I saw from Wikipedia stated that $$ \int_{\Omega} g(x)|\nabla u(x)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{u^{-1}(x)} g(x) \, \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(dx) \right) \, dx $$

Comment: Actually I fail to see why this gives the general solution to the OP question, would you mind to leave an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that we have a theorem called [*coarea formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) which states that if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that both $f$ and $u$ are nice functions on $\Omega$, then

$$ \int_{\Omega} f(\mathrm{x})|\nabla u(\mathrm{x})| \, d\mathrm{x} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{u^{-1}(t)} f(\mathrm{x}) \, \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(d\mathrm{x}) \right) \, d\mathrm{t} $$

Here $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (or simply you may consider it the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface measure). In fact, it only requires $u$ is Lipschitz and $f$ is integrable, but probably this is an overkill.

In our case, this tells that

$$ h(z) = \int_{\{ g(\mathrm{x}) \leq z \}} f(\mathrm{x}) \, d\mathrm{x}
= \int_{-\infty}^{z} \left( \int_{\{ g(\mathrm{x}) = t\}} \frac{f(\mathrm{x})}{|\nabla g(\mathrm{x})|} \, \mathcal{H}^{1}(dx) \right) \, dt $$

and hence we have

$$ h(z)
= \int_{\{ g(\mathrm{x}) = z\}} \frac{f(\mathrm{x})}{|\nabla g(\mathrm{x})|} \, \mathcal{H}^{1}(dx)
= \int_{\{ g(\mathrm{x}) = z\}} \frac{f(\mathrm{x})}{|\nabla g(\mathrm{x})|} \, ds. $$

Here, the last integral is a line integral and the last equality holds when the level set for $g(\mathrm{x}) = z$ is a nice curve.

Comment: I wonder there is no regularity on the open set $\Omega$, especially the boundary issue?

Comment: @user284331, I think we do not bother such issue. The reason is that it suffices to test the equality for only $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, hence we can always localize the claim.